# Why does calling random.random() LESS OFTEN make my program slower?

Tags: python, random, tree

I have a bit of code where I am trying to split a tree into two parts. These parts need to be balanced by population within some ε bound, and I have been using the following code:

```
def find_balanced_edge_cuts_memoization(
    h: PopulatedGraph, choice: Callable = random.choice
) -> List[Cut]:
    """
    Find balanced edge cuts using memoization.

    This function takes a PopulatedGraph object and a choice function as input and returns a list
    of balanced edge cuts. A balanced edge cut is defined as a cut that divides the graph into
    two subsets, such that the population of each subset is close to the ideal population
    defined by the PopulatedGraph object.

    :param h: The PopulatedGraph object representing the graph.
    :type h: PopulatedGraph
    :param choice: The choice function used to select the root node.
    :type choice: Callable, optional

    :returns: A list of balanced edge cuts.
    :rtype: List[Cut]
    """

    root = choice([x for x in h if h.degree(x) > 1])
    pred = predecessors(h.graph, root)
    succ = successors(h.graph, root)
    total_pop = h.tot_pop
    subtree_pops: Dict[Any, Union[int, float]] = {}
    stack = deque(n for n in succ[root])
    while stack:
        next_node = stack.pop()
        if next_node not in subtree_pops:
            if next_node in succ:
                children = succ[next_node]
                if all(c in subtree_pops for c in children):
                    subtree_pops[next_node] = sum(subtree_pops[c] for c in children)
                    subtree_pops[next_node] += h.population[next_node]
                else:
                    stack.append(next_node)
                    for c in children:
                        if c not in subtree_pops:
                            stack.append(c)
            else:
                subtree_pops[next_node] = h.population[next_node]

    def part_nodes(start):
        nodes = set()
        queue = deque([start])
        while queue:
            next_node = queue.pop()
            if next_node not in nodes:
                nodes.add(next_node)
                if next_node in succ:
                    for c in succ[next_node]:
                        if c not in nodes:
                            queue.append(c)
        return nodes

    cuts = []
    for node, tree_pop in subtree_pops.items():

        if abs(tree_pop - h.ideal_pop) <= h.ideal_pop * h.epsilon:
            e = (node, pred[node])
            wt = random.random()
            cuts.append(
                Cut(
                    edge=e,
                    weight=h.graph.edges[e].get("random_weight", wt),
                    subset=part_nodes(node)
                )
            )
        elif abs((total_pop - tree_pop) - h.ideal_pop) <= h.ideal_pop * h.epsilon:
            e = (node, pred[node])
            wt = random.random()
            cuts.append(
                Cut(
                    edge=e,
                    weight=h.graph.edges[e].get("random_weight", wt),
                    subset=set(h.graph.nodes) - part_nodes(node),
                )
            )
    return cuts
```

when I went to profile this bit of code I noticed that one of my tests was running for a really long time, and this function was the main culprit. So I did some nonsense, and I found that changing the last `for` loop to

```
    for node, tree_pop in subtree_pops.items():
        wt = random.random()                                           # <- CHANGE HERE
        if abs(tree_pop - h.ideal_pop) <= h.ideal_pop * h.epsilon:
            e = (node, pred[node])
            cuts.append(
                Cut(
                    edge=e,
                    weight=h.graph.edges[e].get("random_weight", wt),
                    subset=part_nodes(node)
                )
            )
        elif abs((total_pop - tree_pop) - h.ideal_pop) <= h.ideal_pop * h.epsilon:
            e = (node, pred[node])
            cuts.append(
                Cut(
                    edge=e,
                    weight=h.graph.edges[e].get("random_weight", wt),
                    subset=set(h.graph.nodes) - part_nodes(node),
                )
            )
    return cuts
```

improves the execusion speed of my code by ~250-400x depending on the graph that I am working with, and what I would like to understand is WHY. It makes no sense to me that this would be the case since in the first situation the `random.random()` call should be made strictly less than in the second situation and yet this is not reflected in the performace.

Here are the relevant classes that are used in this case:

```
Cut = namedtuple("Cut", "edge weight subset")
```

and

```
class PopulatedGraph:
    """
    A class representing a graph with population information.

    :ivar graph: The underlying graph structure.
    :type graph: nx.Graph
    :ivar subsets: A dictionary mapping nodes to their subsets.
    :type subsets: Dict
    :ivar population: A dictionary mapping nodes to their populations.
    :type population: Dict
    :ivar tot_pop: The total population of the graph.
    :type tot_pop: Union[int, float]
    :ivar ideal_pop: The ideal population for each district.
    :type ideal_pop: float
    :ivar epsilon: The tolerance for population deviation from the ideal population within each
        district.
    :type epsilon: float
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        graph: nx.Graph,
        populations: Dict,
        ideal_pop: Union[float, int],
        epsilon: float,
    ) -> None:
        """
        :param graph: The underlying graph structure.
        :type graph: nx.Graph
        :param populations: A dictionary mapping nodes to their populations.
        :type populations: Dict
        :param ideal_pop: The ideal population for each district.
        :type ideal_pop: Union[float, int]
        :param epsilon: The tolerance for population deviation as a percentage of
            the ideal population within each district.
        :type epsilon: float
        """
        self.graph = graph
        self.subsets = {node: {node} for node in graph.nodes}
        self.population = populations.copy()
        self.tot_pop = sum(self.population.values())
        self.ideal_pop = ideal_pop
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self._degrees = {node: graph.degree(node) for node in graph.nodes}

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.graph)

    def degree(self, node) -> int:
        return self._degrees[node]

    def contract_node(self, node, parent) -> None:
        self.population[parent] += self.population[node]
        self.subsets[parent] |= self.subsets[node]
        self._degrees[parent] -= 1

    def has_ideal_population(self, node) -> bool:
        return (
            abs(self.population[node] - self.ideal_pop) < self.epsilon * self.ideal_pop
        )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        graph_info = (
            f"Graph(nodes={len(self.graph.nodes)}, edges={len(self.graph.edges)})"
        )
        return (
            f"{self.__class__.__name__}("
            f"graph={graph_info}, "
            f"total_population={self.tot_pop}, "
            f"ideal_population={self.ideal_pop}, "
            f"epsilon={self.epsilon})"
        )
```

If anyone could provide some insight into what is going on here, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, please let me know if you need any more information: this is my first time posting here, so I may be unaware of some of the standards, and I appreciate your patience with me. Thank you!

I have looked in the python documentation on how `random.random()` works and tried to look into any information on how this situation might be handled by the interpreter, but didn't get very far. I also made sure that this issue was replicable accross multiple python versions and on multiple machines, and it appears to be the case, so I am genuinely at a loss for what to do next.

Comment: are you able to reproduce this consistently?

Comment: `random.random()` should be a pretty fast function, so the number of calls shouldn't make much difference. What fraction of the items have neither the `if` nor `elif` conditions true?

Comment: Which Python implementation and version are you using? CPython? Could be an optimization pass that triggers only on functions small enough.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Yes, I can reproduce this consistently, and the if or elif block executes ~7% of the time for the tests that I am using.

Comment: I tried this on python 3.11 and 3.9. I used a fresh venv each time and did it on several machines

Comment: Are you using a deterministically seeded random? (You might not be doing it intentionally; some test frameworks do it automatically, for example.) Try using a new `Random` instance.

Comment: I tried that. Several random seeds and a different PYTHONHASHSEED environment variable as well

Comment: What happens if you add a throwaway `random.random()` call in the same place to the original code? I.e. keep the two existing `wt = random.random()`s, then add `_ = random.random()` at the start of the loop body. (Also, any chance you can post a [mre]?)

Comment: Well, that appears to fix the issue across all of my seeds, which is nice, but I am confused as to why that works?

Comment: Now what if you use a separate random instance, initialized at module level, just for those three calls? I.e. `rng = random.Random()` at module level, `_ = rng.random()`, `wt = rng.random()` x 2

Comment: Wait, I found the issue. There was a deterministic seed very sneakily set in one of the functions called before this one that I missed (despite the couple of hours spent looking for it previously).  @Ry, thank you so much for your help!